# Error: dt is a variable but is used like a method

Tags: c#

I'm getting error at dt(0) saying that dt is a variable but is used like a method. 
Thanks for your help. I know this seems very simple, but I can't figure it out. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
private void pubSelectHL7Server()
{

    try
    {
        //-> if valid ip address, no need to get from database.
        if (HL7ServerIP.Trim().Split('.').Length == 4)
            return;
        //Dim ServiceName As String = String.Empty
        //ServiceName = If(My.Settings.ServiceName.ToString.Length = 0, "IMG_JES", My.Settings.ServiceName)

        classDataSource mClsDs = new classDataSource();
        //mClsDs.Add("HL7_SelectServer", "@pServiceName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, ServiceName.ToString());
        mClsDs.Add("HL7_SelectServer", "@pServiceName", (Char)SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, ServiceName);

        using (DataTable dt = mClsDs.GetRs("LABIMAGEDB", "Constultation").Tables[0])
        {
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                HL7ServerIP = dt(0)("ServerIP").ToString();
                HL7SendPort = dt(0)("SendPort").ToString.Trim;
                TempLogFolder = dt(0)("TempLogFolder").ToString.Trim;
                StopSendPort = Module1.CheckNullIntegerToBoolean(dt(0)("StopSendPort"));
            }
        }
        writeMessage("ServiceName " + ServiceName, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        ModuleHl7.WriteExeptionLog(ex, "-PubSelectHL7sERVER.  Error Getting Connection Info");
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe try `dt[0]("ServerIP").ToString` ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you expect the `DataTable` to contain a single `DataRow` and you want to access it's fields. Then you can get them via `DataTable.Rows[0].Field`:

```
HL7ServerIP = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("ServerIP");
```

Note that you don't access arrays or lists with round brackets(as in VB.NET) but squared brackets.